# About Tomcat port number and App Name

Tags: tomcat, vps

I am using a VPS to host a Java web application. I installed Cpanel and then installed Tomcat, Apache, PHP (easyApache) successfully. I used tomcat manager to deploy my War file. I can access the website using the URL:

www.domainname.com:8080/appname

However, I wanted to access my web application using URL: www.domainname.com 
To do this, I used ssh command to access to the tomcat server.xml and changed the port number from 8080 to 80. After I restart Tomcat, when I try to access to the http:www.domainname.com:80, the page is giving an error. When I tried to access using URL: www.domainname.com:80/appname, the page is also giving me an error. (In this case I already put war file and unzipped it to the public_html folder)

Can anyone help me with that?

I just want to link the web application to the domain so that anyone who types www.domainname.com will directly access to the web application.

Comment: What is the error can you please tell.

Comment: i've deleted mine answer now can you please tell what the error is?
Or some Screenshots..  if you've done then please answer yourself